# Multiple problems generating a text file

Tags: python, text-files

I am making my first interface with Pyqt, using "designer" and Python to configure it.The function `def clickconector` return the form fill and `def radio_value` return if the job is pending or finished ("pendiente" or "terminado"). `clickconector` and `radio_value`* functions are written correctly, but I have problems with `def text_file` function.

**Problem #1** : For some reason the generated file has the same inside as the title, which would come if the `radio_value` function, being that it specifies in the algorithm that It was the other function `clickconector`.

**Problem #2** : The title is not being written as I want. I get this: `('Terminado', 'MT16'). txt`, (It is writing `.txt` in the title).
When it should be: `Terminado MT16`. Also, the file type does not appear to me as `.txt`, I have to select to open it like this with the mouse

```
def clickconector (self):
    relleno = [self.bitacora.text(), self.turno.text(), self.asesor.text(), self.item.text(), self.modelo.text(), self.identificacion.text(), self.rig.text(),self.horometro.text(),self.condicion.text(),self.orden.text(), self.observacion.text()]
    form_label = ["bitacora", 'turno', 'asesor', 'item', 'modelo', 'identificacion', 'rig', 'horometro', 'condicion', 'orden', 'observacion']
    for a,b in zip (form_label, relleno):
        return (a,b)
        
def radio_value (self):
    if self.pendiente.isChecked():     
        return 'Pendiente' , self.bitacora.text()
    
    if self.terminado.isChecked():
        return'Terminado', self.bitacora.text()

def text_file (self):
    Bloc_title= self.radio_value()
    f = open(str(Bloc_title)+'. txt', 'w')
    f.write(str(self.clickconector()))   
    return f
```

Comment: What are you trying to write to the file, this is always going to pick the first item from relleno and form_label?

Comment: This is caused by the zip function call it will take turns from the arrays to add elements but you are then only selecting the first of the new larger array

Comment: @User1010 I want to write all the generated elements in zip, "relleno" and "form_label", but it only generates the first one, do you know why?

Comment: how should i fix it? @User1010

Comment: I have amended my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `radio_value` is a `tuple`. You are converting a tuple to a string, so it is going to be printed in the form of a `tuple`, i.e., `"(value_a, value_b, value_c)"` and not `value_a value_b value_c`. You can use `join` to join each value of the tuple with a space, like so:

```py
" ".join(self.radio_value())
```

You also wrote `". txt"` and not `".txt"` in `f = open(str(Bloc_title)+'. txt', 'w')`. That is why `. txt` was in the file name. With all of this in mind, your `text_file` function should look something like this:

```py
def text_file(self):
    filename = f"{' '.join(self.radio_value())}.txt"
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(" ".join(self.clickconnector()))
        return f
```

Note the use of `with/open` instead of just `open`. Using `with/open` is highly recommended for readability and overall ease-of-use.

Comment: This will not provide the desired output filename and will leave the comma

Comment: @gmdev I have another question: in "def clickconector" returns the first tuple only, and I want all touples, I tried a lot of possible solutions, but the error It's the same: TypeError: can only join an iterable. How should I correct that part to have the data for both lists?

Comment: The return statement breaks the for loop. You can return the entire zip by writing: `return list(zip(form_label, relleno))`

Answer (score 1):

Problem 2,

Couple of little issues here you are putting the file ext as `. txt` this should be `.txt`. Note the extra space.

Your `Bloc_title` is a list and so you are getting an array in the title, you will need to extra the parts of this array, this will always be of length 2 so you can do the following,

```py
def text_file (self):
    Bloc_title = self.radio_value()
    f = open(Bloc_title[0] + ' ' + str(Bloc_title[1] + '.txt', 'w')
    f.write(str(self.clickconector()))   
    return f
```

Note the str call may not be required but I am unsure of the data type returned by `self.bitacora.text()`.

Answer from comments,
If you would like all elements from relleno and only the first from form_label I would suggest ammending clickconnector()

```py
def clickconector (self):
    relleno = [self.bitacora.text(), self.turno.text(), self.asesor.text(), self.item.text(), self.modelo.text(), self.identificacion.text(), self.rig.text(),self.horometro.text(),self.condicion.text(),self.orden.text(), self.observacion.text()]
    form_label = ["bitacora", 'turno', 'asesor', 'item', 'modelo', 'identificacion', 'rig', 'horometro', 'condicion', 'orden', 'observacion']
    return [form_label[0]] + relleno
```

Comment: Thank you @User1010 ! One last question, if I wanted to join both lists to show all the elements, how would it be?

Comment: @cfsl You can just add the two lists, relleno + form_label potentially use zip without the for loop

Comment: I have tried to do it, but it does not work because I get an error: TypeError: can only join an iterable. I'm new to this and trying to learn, could you help me with this? It's the last thing I need